# What does !^ (exclamation mark caret) do in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history, command-substitution

Does anyone know what the command `!^` does in the bash shell? I know `!` relates to history expansion and `^` relates to command substitution (when it's not being used in a regular expression when it indicates the beginning of a pattern). But when put together it seems to substitute a command argument in a way that is confusing. Example:

```
:~$ echo "foo"
foo
:~$ !^
"foo"
```

I was using sed search and replace with `!` as the delimiter and `^` to match the beginning of the line and it was giving strange substitutions. I'm using a different delimiter to fix my immediate problem but just curious what's going on.

```
sed -i "s!^\(.*\)\(foo\.sh\)!# \1\2!" foo.txt
```

returns this substituted command

```
sed -i "s"foo"\(.*\)\(foo\.sh\)sed -i "s"foo"\(.*\)\(foo\.sh\) \1\2!" foo.txt
```

Comment: ... or https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html

Comment: Thank you both! Had not heard of Word Designators. That was simple! Sry I'm too new to upvote.